# Show list item with specific word

Tags: java

I would like to show all items from a List, which contain a specific word. Is it possible?

For example a List contains element `AAA, BBB, CCC`. I would like to show list with only `BBB` element.

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you've tried already. What language is this written in - Kotlin? Java?

Comment: you can iterate through the list and use string comparison method .contains("")

Comment: a simple research on the web with key words: `filtering list in "specificLanguage"` would list you a lot of valid pages from where you will have your answer. And not only, you will deeply understand how filtering works.

Comment: Are you looking for exact words? should your filtered list contain `ABBBA` if it is present in the original list?

Comment: implement your business logic and create a hashMap  HashMap<"AAA",ArrayList<String>> for each element or key then after completing this process add them to a final array list

Comment: If this answer is useful in your case, please consider accepting the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852933/show-list-item-with-specific-word/58853421#58853421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java 8 streams API.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC");

    List<String> result = lines.stream()           // convert list to stream
            .filter(line -> "BBB".equals(line))    // we want to filter all fields like "BBB"
            .collect(Collectors.toList());         // collect the output and convert streams to a List

    result.forEach(System.out::println);           // output : BBB, BBB

}
```

If you're not using Java 8, you can iterate through your list and filter it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC");

   List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (String s: lines) {
       if(s.equals("BBB")) {
           filteredList.add(s);
       }
   }

   System.out.println(filteredList);  // output - [BBB, BBB]
}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "CCC");

   for (String s: lines) {
       if(s.equals("BBB")) {
           System.out.println(s);
       }
   }

// output
// BBB
// BBB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the string list and validate each element as per your validation rules or `regex`.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("AAAIU");
list.add("BBBERER");
list.add("BBBBBB");
list.add("TYYYBBB");
list.add("TTYYUU");

for (String s : list) {
    if (s.contains("BBB")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

/* Output */
// BBBERER
// BBBBBB
// TYYYBBB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin you can just use the filter:

`list.filter { it=="BBB" }`

see more here : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-filtering.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the question, if you want all the elements that **contain** `"BBB"` or the ones that **equal** `"BBB"`. Here are both solutions:

Assuming an input list such as :

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("AAAB", "BBBB", "BBB", "AAA", "BB", "BBB", "CBBBCC", "CCC");
```

You can stream it, filter elements that contain/equal `"BBB"` then collect it back into a list:

- If you want all items that **contain** `"BBB"`

  ```
  List<String> filteredItems= items.stream()
      .filter(item -> item.contains("BBB"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

  returns `[BBBB, BBB, BBB, CBBBCC]`
- If you want all items that **equal** `"BBB"`

  ```
  List<String> filteredItems= items.stream()
      .filter(item -> item.equals("BBB"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

  returns `[BBB, BBB]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution with the least amount of code involved would be:

Here the initial list:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "BBB");
```

Here how to retain all elements of the list that equal `BBB`:

```java
list.retainAll(Arrays.asList("BBB"));
```

The original list will then only contain elements with the value `BBB`. In this case this will result in a list with 2 elements.

You can also pass pass multiple values that should be retained. In case `AAA` and `CCC` should be retained, just do the following:

```java
list.retainAll(Arrays.asList("AAA","BBB"));
```

If you then print the list values this would result in `AAA,BBB,BBB`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create the new List and add each element containing the specified value.

```
public static void main(String []args){
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        l1.add("BBBBB");
        l1.add("BBAARA");
        l1.add("CCCCCC");
        l1.add("MMMMBBBB");
        l1.add("AABBBBMMM");

        for (String s : l1) {
          if (s.contains("BBB")) {
              l2.add(s);
           }
        }
         System.out.println(l2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code for filtering list with a specific word "BBB"

================================================

```
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC");
        List<String> resultList = asList.stream().filter(x-> "BBB".equals(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Filterd for BBB "+resultList);
```